# Attaching QUERY_STRING to REQUEST_URI in mod_rewrtie

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm caching full HTML pages. Each cache file is named as the PHP's REQUEST_URI. PHP's REQUEST_URL != mod_rewrite REQUEST_URI. PHP saves files as I want them to be "/foo/bar/file?var1=a&varb=2". My rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]
```

Will obviously fail because QUERY_STRING is not appended. What would be the best way to modify my Rule in order to check the real file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the CSA (Query String append) flag does not apply, but if I understood your question correctly you could match the query string in a RewriteCond and append it to the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([.*)$
```

which is then accessible as %n in your RewriteRule.

Comment: Oh, apologies for my introductory sentence, it may well be that I need to re-read your question - from what I can see you're not just after appending the existing query string. Again, my apologies.
Still your question does not seem to be terribly clear on what you are trying to achieve exactly. Maybe you could add an example of you input and desired result.

Comment: I guess it sort of answer my question. Thank you for that.